# Entity Framework nested table query to JSON

Tags: c#, json, lambda, nested, entity-framework-5

```
public class Module
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string moduleName { get; set; }
    //navigation property
    public virtual HashSet<Policy> policies { get; set; }
}

public class Policy
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    //foreign keys
    public int subscriberId { get; set; }
    //navigation properties
    public virtual Subscriber subscriber { get; set; }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int subscriptionId { get; set; }
    // Navigation property 
    public virtual HashSet<Policy> policies { get; set; }
}
```

I have 3 related objects.

> Module - Policy - Subscriber

- A module has multiple policies
- A policy has one subscriber

I need to list all the policies and subscribers under a certain module in `JSON` format. Due to the posts that I found on web I created this query:

```
        return db.modules
            .Where(m => m.id == id)
            .Include (m => m.policies.Select(p => p.subscriber))
            .Select(m => new {
                m.id,
                m.moduleName,
                m.policies
            }) ;
```

This only gives the result below. As you can see the details of Subscriber entity under policies are not present `(NULL)` :( What is wrong?

```
[{"id":1,"moduleName":"module1",
  "policies":[{"id":1,"subscriberId":1,"subscriber":null}]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using dynamics in your Select method, you have to build it all out like this:

```
return db.modules
    .Where(m => m.id == id)
    .Include (m => m.policies.Select(p => p.subscriber))
    .Select(m => new {
        m.id,
        m.moduleName,
        policies = m.policies.Select(p => new
        {
            p.id,
            p.subscriberId,
            subscriber = new
            {
                p.subscriber.id,
                p.subscriber.name,
                p.subscriber.subscriptionId,
            }
        }
    });
```

I typically use real Dto classes so if the Dto ever needs to be updated, refactoring will work properly. I would also consider using a DtoFactory to handle the construction, but you could do it with linq like this:

```
public class ModuleDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string moduleName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<PolicyDto> policies { get; set; }
}
public class PolicyDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int subscriberId { get; set; }
    public SubscriberDto subscriber { get; set; }
}
public class SubscriberDto
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int subscriptionId { get; set; }
}    

...other code here...

return db.modules
    .Where(m => m.id == id)
    .Include (m => m.policies.Select(p => p.subscriber))
    .Select(m => new ModuleDto {
        m.id,
        m.moduleName,
        policies = m.policies.Select(p => new PolicyDto
        {
            p.id,
            p.subscriberId,
            subscriber = new SubsciberDto
            {
                p.subscriber.id,
                p.subscriber.name,
                p.subscriber.subscriptionId,
            }
        }
    });
```

It gets a little messy to read the linq statement. This is why I typically use a DtoFactory to generate the Dtos from the models.